# Python click group: How to have -h/--help for all commands

Tags: python, python-click

**Context:**

I'm having several scripts with loads of sub commands that I'd like to convert to using `click`

At the moment all these commands do accept `-h` and `--help` in order to display help options. I'd like to keep this behavior.

**Problem:**

click accepts by default `--help` to display the help text, but not `-h`

for a click command this can be changed easily by adding.

```
@click.group()
@click.help_option("--help", "-h")
def cli():
    """ the doc string """
    enter code here

@cli.command()
@click.help_option("--help", "-h")
def mycommand()
    pass

@cli.command()
@click.help_option("--help", "-h")
def mycommand1()
    pass

...
```

However if I'm having tens of commands I have to reapply the decorator line

```
@click.help_option("--help", "-h")
```

fort each sub command.

Would there be any trick to avoid having to write this line everywhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define a CONTEXT_SETTINGS and use it like this:

```
CONTEXT_SETTINGS = dict(help_option_names=['-h', '--help'])

@click.command(context_settings=CONTEXT_SETTINGS)
def cli():
    pass
```

From the click [documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/documentation/#help-texts):

> Help Parameter Customization Changelog The help parameter is
>   implemented in Click in a very special manner. Unlike regular
>   parameters it’s automatically added by Click for any command and it
>   performs automatic conflict resolution. By default it’s called --help,
>   but this can be changed. If a command itself implements a parameter
>   with the same name, the default help parameter stops accepting it.
>   There is a context setting that can be used to override the names of
>   the help parameters called help_option_names.
>
> This example changes the default parameters to -h and --help instead
>   of just --help:
>
> CONTEXT_SETTINGS = dict(help_option_names=['-h', '--help'])
>
> @click.command(context_settings=CONTEXT_SETTINGS) def cli():
>       pass And what it looks like:
>
> $ cli -h Usage: cli [OPTIONS]
>
> Options:   -h, --help  Show this message and exit.

Comment: works perfectly.
Was going through the doc and still missed this section.

Now I have to write 
 `@cli.command(context_settings=CONTEXT_SETTINGS)` for every command

but at least I don't need a second line with `@click.help_option("--help", "-h")`


Thanks

Comment: @Omar, if you could add in your (already good) answer that it's possible to provide this `context_settings` parameter to the `click.CommandCollection` arguments, providing this behaviour to all the commands and groups mentioned in the `sources` parameter, it would make it perfect! (_e.g._ `click.CommandCollection(sources=[custom_group],context_settings={'help_option_names': ['-h', '--help']})`)

Answer (score 0):

for anyone looking to alias the version to `--version|-v`, just pass the aliases after the version

```py
@click.version_option(
    "0.0.1",
    "--version",
    "-v",
)
@click.group()
def cli():
    pass
```